# Does Spring Data JDBC support custom type converters

Tags: java, oracle, spring-data-jdbc

I have an entity that has a filed of type `java.util.Date` (or `Timestamp`, doesn't matter for the case).

```
public class StatusReason {
    @Column("SRN_ID")
    private Long id;
    @Column("SRN_CREATOR")
    private String creator;
    @Column("SRN_REASON")
    private String reason;
    @Column("SRN_STATUS")
    private String status;
    @Column("SRN_TIMESTAMP")
    private Date timestamp;
//getters, setters, etc...
}
```

The database is Oracle and the corresponding column is of type `TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE`

When I call any of the default `findById` or `findAll` methods of the repository I get:
`ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ] to type [java.util.Date]`.

I can create a custom `RowMapper` for the type and it will work fine. 
I was just wondering if it's possible to register a custom converter (in my case from `oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ` to `java.util.Date`) so can still benefit from the default mapping and use the converter through the whole app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can register custom conversions by inheriting your configuration from [`JdbcConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/blob/dd7362516b4a6de60c87b739374e05448209c158/spring-data-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jdbc/repository/config/JdbcConfiguration.java) (Spring Data JDBC v1.x) or [`AbstractJdbcConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/blob/2.2.x/spring-data-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jdbc/repository/config/AbstractJdbcConfiguration.java) (v2.x). Then overwrite the method [`jdbcCustomConversions()`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/blob/dd7362516b4a6de60c87b739374e05448209c158/spring-data-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jdbc/repository/config/JdbcConfiguration.java#L78).

[`JdbcCustomConversions`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/1.0.2.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/jdbc/core/convert/JdbcCustomConversions.html) takes a list of `Converter` as an argument.

Comment: Thanks, Jens! Love the project, by the way.

Comment: Glad you do. BTW: Feel free to create an issue for the missing conversion.

Comment: Is it not https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/issues/629 ?